# Socket.io java server implementation for 1.4.5 or higher

Tags: java, socket.io, atmosphere

i have an issue: 
I need to use Socket.IO, cause of compatibility with many devices written on c#, objective C, and Java(Socket.io has client libs for all of em). The server side is written in Java, i've tried atmosphere framework - it's ok, not good as sock.js spring integration, but it compatibles with socket.io protocol version 1, fresh client libs use version 3. 
Will be glad of any suggestions. Maybe it's possible to tune atmosphere or to tune client library of socket.io?